# Problem with the depth of nested elements inside list/tuple

Tags: python

Typing first time here, before i found many helpful tips in stackoverflow, right now i have black hole in my brain and can't figure out how to solve this:

i got:

```
    dirlist = ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'dir4']
    print [('a','b','c'),('x','y','z'),[('/tmp/9/', 'X', e) for e in dirlist ] ]
```

ant it outputs:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'),('x', 'y', 'z'), [('/tmp/9/', 'X', 'dir1'), ('/tmp/9/', 'X', 'dir2'), ('/tmp/9/', 'X', 'dir3'), ('/tmp/9/', 'X', 'dir4')]]
```

and i want:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'),('x', 'y', 'z'), ('/tmp/9/', 'X', 'dir1'), ('/tmp/9/', 'X', 'dir2'), ('/tmp/9/', 'X', 'dir3'), ('/tmp/9/', 'X', 'dir4')]
```

... and the real problem is that i need to do it in one line, in the print statement.
Thank you for any suggestions, help needed.

Comment: You need to do it in one line - homework?

Answer (score 8):

```
print [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('x', 'y', 'z')] + [('/tmp/9/', 'X', e) for e in dirlist]
```

Comment: i should ask for help 35min ago ... so i would be sleeping already, thank you. Damn append arggrrr...